# How do I print a millisecond count from epoch as a date-time in UTC using Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I am trying to use Java to format a time in milliseconds into a date in UTC. I have the following code:

```
long ms = 1427590800000;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.ROOT);
cal.setTimeInMillis(ms);
Date date = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); // 2015-03-29 02:00:00
```

This is printing a time in BST (i.e. using the default time-zone) rather than UTC. It seems like the time-zone being set on the calendar has no bearing on the date being printed.

The actual time in UTC is shown by the following python snippet:

```
import datetime
ms = 1427590800000
print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ms/1000.0) # 2015-03-29 01:00:00
```

Setting the default JVM time-zone to "UTC" results in the correct date being printed, but this doesn't seem like a safe solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format). **Please search StackOverflow** before posting. This topic has been addressed *many* times already.

Comment: The linked question makes no mention of UTC, and the accepted answer doesn't have the required step of setting the time-zone on the format.

Comment: Duplicate of [Java it to milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20158632/642706), and duplicate of [Date in to UTC format Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238280/date-in-to-utc-format-java) and many many more. I'll ask again, please search StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `timezone` to the formatter before formatting if you want a desired timezone.

Use `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` and then call `dateFormat.format(date)`

Comment: Thanks, that means I don't need to use the `Calendar` at all.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

Parse as an `Instant`, a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
long input = 1_427_590_800_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2015-03-29T01:00:00Z

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).